# Shapefile to Topojson conversion

Tags: geojson, shapefile, topojson

I am trying to convert the Ghana admin1 shapefile that can be found [here](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/shp/GHA_adm.zip). My end goal is to obtain a TopoJSON as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925131/shapefile-to-topojson-conversion-problems).
I have used this command on a Linux machine:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON GHA_adm1.json GHA_adm1.shp
```

And it returns this:

```
Unable to open datasource `GHA_adm1.shp' with the following drivers.
... here goes a long list of drivers...
```

I am I doing something wrong? Should I install other "drivers"? But how? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use nodejs, npm ? If so, you can use `topojson` npm package to convert shp into topojson.

Comment: Indeed @Hugolpz. In the question linked above, the person first convert its file to GeoJson before going to the TopoJson.
And I believe I do use the `topojson`package.

Comment: If your aim is to convert to topojson, you use topojson command line tool anyway. If you don't need any advanced functions (reprojection, clipping, etcs), better to directly convert from shp to topojson.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Download the GIS source

GADM is the perfect source for administrative GIS files.

> GADM.org > [Download page](http://www.gadm.org/country) : select your country and format "shapefile" > ok.

Or via terminal (replace New Ghana code `GHA` by your target country's iso code):

```
# prepare folder
mkdir -p ./map; cd ./map
curl http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js -O -J
curl http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js -O -J
# download data
curl \
    -L -C - 'http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/shp/GHA_adm.zip' \
    -o ./GHA_adm.zip
unzip -n ./GHA_adm.zip -d ./
```

#### shp to topojson

Use [topojson command line](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference), it's more direct. If you want to keep all properties :

```
 topojson -q 1e4 \
          -o out.json \
          -- in1.shp in2.shp
```

You can also select attributes from the shapfiles, and rename them on the go :

```
 topojson \
    --bbox \
    --id-property none \
    -p name=NAME_1 \
    -p code=ID_1 \
    -p L0=NAME_0 \
    -q 1e4 \
    --filter=small \
    -o GHA_adm_w.topo.json \
    -- admin_1=GHA_adm1.shp admin_2=GHA_adm2.shp
```

For GHA, there is no attribute in the .shp suitable for a good ID. `NAME_1` have spaces which will give invalid `id` within your HTML.

[image]

#### Inspect json

Use http://jsoneditoronline.org . Inspecting your json will give you clues of **what** data is available, and **where** (dot notation path). The [topojson distillery](http://hugolpz.github.io/distillery/) help to preview any topojson and if the code is correct.

#### D3js call

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>
.L1 {
    fill: #E0E0E0;
    stroke: #FFF;
    stroke-width:1px;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="./d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var mapIt = function(width, url){
    console.log("mapIt(): start");
    var height = width/960*500;
    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
          .scale(1)
          .translate([0, 0]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

    d3.json(url, function (error, json) {
        var admin_1 = topojson.feature(json, json.objects.admin_1);

        /* Autofocus code comes here ! */

        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(admin_1.features)
          .enter().append("path")
            .attr('d', path)
            .attr('class', 'L1');
    });    
};
mapIt(960,"http://somesite.org/data/NZL_adm.topo.json");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Focus

A correct autofocus will need a small bit of code from [Mike Bostocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14691788/1974961), example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18426451/1974961):

```
// Compute the bounds of a feature of interest, then derive scale & translate.
var b = path.bounds(admin_1),
    s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height),
    t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];

// Update the projection to use computed scale & translate.
projection
    .scale(s)
    .translate(t);
```

---

**EDIT:** Should work now. Live demo: [**bl.ocks.org**](http://bl.ocks.org/hugolpz/4f8d6eaeaf41c72e268b)

Comment: Thks! This is very helpful. I used the second command you posted to convert from .shp to topoJSON. However, I can't have the html to work. (I used your code and adjusted the url's). Could you give me your opinion on [the output file I got](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x82q06vrz16ew22/GHA_adm1.topo.json?dl=0) for me to assess if the error comes from the json, my code or something else.

Comment: The data seems good, both [jsoneditoronline.org](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=2a258f4a03a0a8352bc00651055a953f) and the [Distillery](http://hugolpz.github.io/distillery/). I wrote this code from memory, need to check it out.

Comment: Indeed, I made some minor mistakes. Working demo now on http://bl.ocks.org/hugolpz/4f8d6eaeaf41c72e268b

Comment: Amazing job and very informative for entry level users like me. Thks.

Comment: I used your question to write down a long due tutorial on how to make maps via gadm and D3js.

Comment: See also [Converting GADM world shp to topojson : Aborted (core dumped)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680635/)

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly fine over here:

> GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24

Perhaps you're running an outdated version of GDAL? You can check your version by using: `ogr2ogr --version`

Comment: My version is `GDAL 2.0.0dev, released 2014/04/16`.

Comment: That should be great :( I don't think there's a way to add/remove drivers, i guess it would be best to try a recompile/install. You could always try to ask this in  http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I might have two concurrent GDAL installations.. I am trying to locate the files.